# Why screenshot insert a label automatically on the capture file

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I usually use the screenshot feature with Shift + Command + 4 in the screen area on OS X. Occasionally, a label appears in the capture as if something was selected. Is it an OS X error? Is it a configuration issue? See the attached screenshot.

[image]